# Make python http server route to different ports

Tags: python, http, httpserver, gil

There was old same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680/how-do-i-write-a-python-http-server-to-listen-on-multiple-ports), but answer was about using threads. I thought it isn't ok with GIL.

I want to make many different HTTP-servers(not even python) which run on different ports and in different processes. And I want to route requests from port 80 to them by some parameter(for example HTTP_HOST).

Should I use HTTP client on server-side(in router) to do request to ports, or there is a different way?

I want to do something like nginx does, but I want it to change dynamically.

Comment: And why wouldn't apache virtualhosts work for you?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco looks like with apache virtualhosts I need to restart httpd each time I add server. It's unacceptable.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might want to check out: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html